# Remove all unused in code imports Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, coding-style

I'm developing for a project using Java 8, but we've disabled the strictness of doclint, so it is not necessary to import classes only used in javadocs. Is there a way to remove imports that are not used in code, even if they are in javadocs?

Ex:

```
import com.website.project.subpackage.Foo; //This import isn't needed.
import com.website.project.Baz;

/**
 * Gets {@link Baz}es for use, often with {@link Foo#setCurrentBaz}.
*/
public class Bar
{
    public Baz getBaz()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

EDIT: Ctrl + Shift + O is not the anwser, as it will not remove imports that are used in javadocs.

Comment: `<ctrl> + <shift> + o`

Comment: `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`o` ?

Comment: Wouldn't that make your javadoc *wrong*? You could always put the fully qualified name in the javadoc.

Comment: @immibis In Java 7 and earlier, unless there was a conflict, the javadoc parser could find the correct class without an import. Java 8's doclint made it more strict, but without it it remains correct.

Answer (score 0):

I think is

> shift+ctrl+O

maybe this will solve that problem

Answer (score 0):

`Ctrl + Shift + o` will remove all unused imports, and (try to) add the required imports in Eclipse.